# I can't write simple unattended ftp command line

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, ftp

i am trying to write a bat file on windows xp. I can connect ftp server and download files by console but i can't make it work by unattended bat file.

ftp 127.0.0.1 //connect server but ask username and password manualy how can i connect autamticly with password ?

i have tried ftp 127.0.0.1 pass pass but doesn't work. [all commands here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftp.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: /* Missing tag: windows */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this as a batch file and run it

```
echo user  >> ftpcommands.txt
echo myusername>> ftpcommands.txt
echo mypassword>> ftpcommands.txt
echo get file1>> ftpcommands.txt
echo get file2>> ftpcommands.txt
echo quit  >> ftpcommands.txt
ftp -n -s:ftpcommands.txt ftp.example.com
del ftpcommands.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

I tend to avoid batching with vanilla windows FTP. I recommend trying out [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php): It's free, it's got robust scripting capabilities, and it's got a lot more features than the default FTP client that comes with Windows.

Comment: Honestly i just interested in native windows scripting more.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-s:script.txt` method of scripting, as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=96269).  Basically, you create a script file like this:

```
user
myusername
mypassword
get file1
quit
```

And invoke it like so:

`ftp -n -s:script.txt ftp.example.com`

Comment: but problem is we are using 2 files so i have to always send 2 file there and this is what i don't want. I can do all my job by command line but i cant make unattended batch file yet :{

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is write commands into text file then send that text file as parameter.

```
echo user nod32 nod32 >ftp.txt

echo get my.text d:\my.txt >> ftp.txt

echo cd Books >>ftp.txt

ftp -n -s:ftp.txt localhost
```